# Will it notify my mom if i turn my phone on?

Tags: iphone

I got my phone taken away and i found it in my moms dresser turned off. She uses Find my Friends on me so will it notify her if i turn it on? She also pays the bill if that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 3):

**Potentially.**

If your mom selected the 'notify when at this location' switch, your phone will notify her when it comes online at your house. It is highly unlikely that this is enabled, though.

However, this will show your phone as online, so if she happens to check Find my Friends while your phone is turned on, she will be able to see it on the map.